# How to replace Bar Buttons with images, similar to Facebook?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm prototyping an app right now. I added a bunch of bar buttons to my nav bar programatically:

```
NSArray *buttonTitles = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Alerts", @"Causes", @"Msgs", @"My Work", @"My Posts", nil];

NSMutableArray *rightBarButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    rightButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 34);
    [rightButton setTitle:[buttonTitles objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    rightButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
    rightItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightButton];
    [rightBarButtons addObject:rightItem];   
}
```

Right now, they look really ugly, especially against the nav bar. I want to take some images (similar to tab bar images) and put them there to replace the buttons. How would I do this?

Sorry for my stupidity, I'm new to this.

Thanks!

Comment: is the rightButton the object you wish to change into an image?

Answer (score 0):

```
 [rightButton setBackgroundImage:@"image.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

would do the trick if i understand your question correctly.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    NSString* imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image-%d", i];
    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    rightButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 34);
    [rightButton setTitle:[buttonTitles objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    rightButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
    [rightButton setBackgroundImage:imageName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    rightItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightButton];
    [rightBarButtons addObject:rightItem];   
}
```

Alright this is how we can do it.
I created a NSString (imageName) assigned the string with the value of image-%d which means it will take the name as `image-1` when `i` is 1 and `image-2` when `i` is 2.

then at the `[rightButton setBackgroundImage:imageName forState:UIControlStateNormal];` part it just takes the name of string we created (imageName).

This means that your images should be named `image-0` through `image-5` because of your loop.

If you need me to clear anything up i'll be happy to explain more.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I'm trying to have a different image for each button, which is where I'm running into an issue.

would I use some if () statements in viewDidLoad or something else?

Thanks